# add base64 decoded picture to upload form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Is there a way to add encoded image to the form taken from webcam? I can print image for prewiew, but I need to upload to the server, I have upload form for images, so I need to use same form for uploading camera images (if possible).

```
 var result = cameraApi.save();
 $('.items-list').append('<img src=data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result + ' />');
```

This code is for displaying taken image, please advice how to instantly add it to upload form.

Comment: You could make a hidden input with the base64 value, and then decode it on server. You cannot create a real file input with programmatically attached files. You can also do a real file upload with ajax, if you convert the base64 into a blob, but not a standard form file upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add random files to `<input type="file">` controls. That's basic browser security, so sites cannot steal files in your hard disk.

But you don't need an upload control at all if you already have the file contents in a JavaScript variable! Just add it to a hidden field or make an AJAX post request.